Kernel of a group ring morphism
I am currently working on group rings. Namely, for a group $G$ and a (commutative unital) ring $R$, a group ring of $G$ over $R$ is a ring denoted $RG$ of elements
$$\sum_{g\in G} a_g \, g, \text{ such that for all } g \in G \text{ except a finite number}, a_g = 0.$$
We know that if we take a group morphism $\varphi : G \to H$, there is a unique ring morphism $R\varphi : RG \to RH$ such that
$$R\varphi(a) = a \text{ for } a \in R \text{ and } R\varphi(g) = \varphi(g) \text{ for } g \in G.$$
Then, I would like to know if there is a relation between $\ker(\varphi)$ and $\ker(R\varphi)$ ?
So far, I couldn't find any answer in books and starting from the basic definition
$$\ker(R\varphi) = \left\{ \sum_{g\in G} a_g g \, | \, \sum_{g\in G} a_g \varphi(g) = 0 \right\}$$
didn't tell me anything on how to related this to $\ker(\varphi)$. In particular, what one could say if $\varphi$ is injective ?
Many thanks in advance for any help or hint.

@ArturoMagidin you are absolutely correct. I took a bad example of how the kernels would be related. I will edit and remove this. Do you have any idea of how they could be related ?

$\sum_{g\in G} a_gg\in\ker(R\varphi)$ iff $\forall h\in H\quad\sum_{\varphi(g)=h}a_g=0$. This can be rewritten in terms of $\ker\varphi$ but it is more heavy.

@AnneBauval Merci ! If I understand correctly, this means that, in particular, if $\varphi$ is injective, there is at most one $g \in G$ such that $h=\varphi(g)$. So, in that case all $a_g$s in the summation $\sum_{g\in G} a_g g$ vanish which prove that $R\varphi$ is injective, right ?

Oui.${}{}{}{} $

@AnneBauval Does the rewriting in terms on the kernel have to do with the bijection between $G$ and $\ker(\varphi) \times G/\ker(\varphi)$ ?

If you want. Alternatively (at the cost of some obvious redundancy but without choosing such a bijection): $\sum_{g\in G}a_gg\in\ker(R\varphi)$ iff $$\forall g\in G\quad\sum_{k\in\ker\varphi}a_{gk}=0.$$
